# In Common Lisp how do I preserve the case of variable output

Tags: common-lisp

I have a variable of a list of cons cells here?

```
 (defparameter lookup-animal  '((Cat . kitten) (Bear . cub) (Cow . calf)))
```

Here is the function I use to parse through them

```
(defun lookup-animal (name type)
  (if (eq type 'old)
    (setf name (car (assoc name lookup-animal)))
  (if (eq type 'young)
    (setf name (cdr (assoc name lookup-animal)))))
  name)

 I run (lookup-animal 'Cat 'old) and it would output > CAT
 I run (lookup-animal 'Cat 'YOUNG) and it would output > KITTEN
```

The issue is I would like the name variable at the bottom of the list of defun lookup-animal to preserve the case of the animal list for example, `Cat` should print `Cat` not `CAT`, and `Bear` should print as `Bear` not `BEAR`. I looked over the internet for 3 hours and got nada...I got uppercase, lowercase no preserve case...so if anyone can help me in the code above preserve the case of the output of the final variable `name` in the function `lookup-animal` while keeping it the red color of a `PRINC` not the pinkish color of `FORMAT`..I would really grateful..

Thanks

Edit:

Here is my current code...It just prints "NAME" instead of the data.  SYMBOL-NAME  was working at REPL as is don't understand the change...I'll still could use help figuring out how to preserve the case of the cons cell data.

```
(defun lookup (name language o)
    (if (eq language 'lisp)
      (setf name (car (assoc name lookup)))
    (if (eq language 'C++)
      (setf name (cdr (assoc name lookup)))))

(setf (readtable-case *readtable*)  :preserve)
(SETF O (SYMBOL-NAME 'NAME))
(SETF (READTABLE-CASE *READTABLE*)  :UPCASE)
o)
```

Comment: Here is some information on symbol cases in common lisp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375537/why-is-common-lisp-case-insensitive   - It might be worth considering whether it's preferable to separate the symbolic representation of the data from the presentation format --- this could be implemented with an additional assoc list from symbols to strings.

Comment: @user3411335: I believe the answer about readtable-case :invert in the linked question will produce the behavior you are trying to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve the case of a symbol with vertical bars ("pipe symbol"):

```
? (defparameter l '((cat . |Kitten|) (bear . |Cub|)))
L
? l
((CAT . |Kitten|) (BEAR . |Cub|))
```

then

```
? (assoc 'cat l)
(CAT . |Kitten|)
? (cdr (assoc 'cat l))
|Kitten|
? (type-of (cdr (assoc 'cat l)))
SYMBOL
```

If you want to print the symbol without the bars,:

```
? (princ (cdr (assoc 'cat l)))
Kitten                    ; printout
|Kitten|                  ; return value
? (format t "Meow said the ~a" (cdr (assoc 'cat l)))
Meow said the Kitten      ; printout
NIL                       ; return value
```

See [here](http://www.cliki.net/case%20sensitivity) and [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/02_cd.htm).

Comment: @Thank you very much...I couldn't find that info anywhere online...What a simple elegant answer...I accepted your answer and voted it up...A very good day to you

Answer (score 2):

You're printing out a symbol, not a string. By convention, the symbol reader in lisp reads symbols in upper case (so when you get to writing them, they're written as upper case strings).

You can change this behavior for the reader like so:

```
(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :preserve)
```

printing might work the way you want to, then. Or, you may need to call:

```
(SYMBOL-NAME 'Cat)
```

Comment: I noticed when I  ran `(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :preserve)` I couldn't enter any functions unless they were uppercase...so I tried `(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :preserve)` then ran function then ran `(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :downcase)` to reverse and now I can't run any function upper or lowercase unless I restart emacs.....Thanks for getting back to be btw:)...so what is the opposite of :preserve ...because what u said worked but it had side effects.

Comment: I think you want to run `(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :upcase)` to revert. That said - you're printing out a symbol, not a string. Printing out symbols is probably a bad idea - it's a bad code smell. You're probably looking to print out a string.

Answer (score 2):

I would not advise that a lisp beginner tinker with the readtable-case.  Few common lisp programs use that facility.

First you should become comfortable with the difference between symbols and string, and the role of *print-case* and *read-case*.

Learning how to use format will be a skill you can use a lot, and there in you will find tools for gaining fine control over your output.

```
> (let ((*print-case* :upcase)) (format t "~A ~(~A~) ~@(~A~) ~:(~A~) ~:@(~A~)" 'cow 'cow 'cow 'cow 'cow))
COW cow Cow Cow COW
nil
> (let ((*print-case* :downcase)) (format t "~A ~(~A~) ~@(~A~) ~:(~A~) ~:@(~A~)" 'cow 'cow 'cow 'cow 'cow))
cow cow Cow Cow COW
nil
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..It taught me alot but I didn't stress enough in my post that I do need to preserve the upper lower case letters...I should have mentioned, I don't know what the words will look like before they are parsed but either way it's mandatory that I preserve the letters as is...so if i parsed "caT" I would need function to print "caT".. Sorry I didn't stress that enough:)...I understand your point of view now though and will adjust future posts accordingly.

Comment: @blueberryfields can u check out my latest edit...just could use someone to show me how to do it