# lisp convert to string uppercase

Tags: symbols, uppercase, clisp

I would like to convert an atom to a string to check if the first letter is a capital letter but with Clisp the function string returns uppercase letters si I can't apply it to my atom.

Example :

```
(setq a 'ljlkj)
(upper-case-p (char (string a)  0))     ----> returns T (and I want nil)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: why are you trying to check case of characters in symbol names? this seems like an eminently wrong thing to do!

Comment: Because I have a programm with lists like this : (Hello it is a sentence) and I don't want to reorganize all my code to have lists like this : ("Hello" "it" "is "a" "sentence"), although I will maybe have to.

Comment: In that case you should set `readtable-case` to `:preserve` before reading your sentences (they are in a file, not interspersed with your code, right?) You can also quote the stuff in your code with `|`: `(setq a '|Hello|)`

Comment: Actually I get the sentences with (read-line) so the sole solution that I have is to redefine readtable :preserve each time I read the input and each time I want to know if the first letter is a capital letter?

Comment: I am not sure it is a good idea to store words as symbols. But if you are sure of your approach, I would define my own readtable variable and bind `*readtable*` to it when I read sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Common Lisp reader](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_b.htm) is case-converting ([step 7](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/23_ab.htm)) by default.
This is [controlled](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/23_aba.htm) by the accessor [`readtable-case`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rdtabl.htm):

```
 (defun test-readtable-case-reading ()
   (let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable nil)))
     (format t "READTABLE-CASE  Input   Symbol-name~
              ~%-----------------------------------~
              ~%")
     (dolist (readtable-case '(:upcase :downcase :preserve :invert))
       (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) readtable-case)
       (dolist (input '("ZEBRA" "Zebra" "zebra"))
         (format t "~&:~A~16T~A~24T~A"
                 (string-upcase readtable-case)
                 input
                 (symbol-name (read-from-string input)))))))
```

The output from `(test-readtable-case-reading)` should be as follows:

```
 READTABLE-CASE     Input Symbol-name
 -------------------------------------
    :UPCASE         ZEBRA   ZEBRA
    :UPCASE         Zebra   ZEBRA
    :UPCASE         zebra   ZEBRA
    :DOWNCASE       ZEBRA   zebra
    :DOWNCASE       Zebra   zebra
    :DOWNCASE       zebra   zebra
    :PRESERVE       ZEBRA   ZEBRA
    :PRESERVE       Zebra   Zebra
    :PRESERVE       zebra   zebra
    :INVERT         ZEBRA   zebra
    :INVERT         Zebra   Zebra
    :INVERT         zebra   ZEBRA
```

See the excellent answer to [Why is Common Lisp case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375537/why-is-common-lisp-case-insensitive) for the reasons *why* the CL reader is case-converting.

Comment: Thank for your respose, I'm sorry but when I do this : (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert) and after this : (setq a (string 'lkj)) I still have LKJ

Comment: Of course you do. This is the correct documented behavior which follows from the code above. Try `(setq a (string `LKJ))` instead.

Comment: Oups, yes sorry. But I still can't know if the first letter of a word is a capital letter unless I use :preserve, but after this lisp functions don't work. Is the sole way to redefine readtable-case every time I want to check this?