# Case Sensitivity Common Lisp

Tags: windows, debugging, common-lisp, case-sensitive

I'm trying to make [sbcl](http://www.sbcl.org/) case sensitive with no success.
Does anyone know what the problem might be?  It [mentions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375537/why-is-common-lisp-case-insensitive) and [here](http://www.cliki.net/case%20sensitivity) that is possible.

I'm running

```
(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert)
(defun hi () "Hi!")
(HI)
(HI)
"Hi!"
```

Inside of the repl like the following.

```
"C:\Program Files\Steel Bank Common Lisp\1.2.15\sbcl.exe" --core "C:\Program Files\Steel Bank Common Lisp\1.2.15\sbcl.core"
```

**EDIT:** So it appears if you call a function with out case sensitivity in Common Lisp it reverts back to its old behavior of being in case sensitive for the rest of the program I have found no way of preventing this currently.

```
; in: Hi2
;     (|Hi2|)
;
; caught style-warning:
;   undefined function: Hi2
;
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     Hi2
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002C77BE3}>:
  The function COMMON-LISP-USER::|Hi2| is undefined.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
```

Comment: As a side note I'm aware of the `(|Fun| args)` syntax and I am not looking for that as an answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @Linuxios Because I'm trying to interface code with c which is case sensitive.

Comment: Your first example can't work. You would need to write `(hi)` to call the function.

Comment: @RainerJoswig My point is that it does work meaning it doesn't respect the case sensitivity setting.

Comment: I just typed it into SBCL at the REPL and it does not work.

Comment: @RainerJoswig What os are you on it might only be a Windows bug.

Comment: What should it have to do with Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common Lisp is *always* case-sensitive.  Symbols have names, which are simply strings. However, there are few things that make things seem sort of case-insensitive.  To grasp what these are, you need to know a little bit about how the system reads code.

When the system reads a form, it has to create a Lisp object from the textual representation.  E.g., if the reader is reading from a string like: `(hello world)`, then the result should be a list of two symbols.  What are the *names* of those symbols?  That's where there's some flexibility in the reader.  The default behavior is for the reader to *upcase* the names that are read from the input.  The reader gets the input "hello" and "world", then *upcases* these to "HELLO" and "WORLD", and then interns those.  This is controlled by the readtable case, as you've discovered.  There are a few different possibilities, viz., :upcase, :downcase, :preserve, and :invert.  :Preserve and :invert can be handy for interoperability code.

There's no sense in which a function has case-sensitivity or doesn't.  The readtable case only affects how the reader turns the textual input into symbol names.  It sounds like what you want to do is ensure that the readtable-case is :preserve or :invert when you're reading your code. Note that if the readtable-case is :invert, then all-lower-case names get upcased, all-upper-case names get downcased, and everything else is preserved.  I point this out because in your example **(defun hi () "Hi!")**, the text "hi" will be upcased, and the symbol on which you're defining a function will have the name "HI".  Then, when you write **(HI)**, the reader will generate a list of a symbol named "hi", which can't be the same symbol.

---

The code provided so far doesn't work the way your example shows it working, and it doesn't look like a copy-and-paste REPL transcript.  Here's what I see (and expect) when I run the code you showed:

```
* (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert)

:invert
* (defun hi () "hello")

hi
```

Writing **(hi)** works, because the reader still inverts and gives you a symbol named "HI", as expected:

```
* (hi)

"hello"
```

But writing **(HI)** doesn't, because the reader inverts and gives you a symbol named "hi", as expected:

```
* (HI)
; in: HI
;     (|hi|)
; 
; caught style-warning:
;   undefined function: HI
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     HI
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002FDE7D3}>:
  The function COMMON-LISP-USER::|hi| is undefined.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

("undefined function")
```

---

Now, in testing this interactively, you *do* need to be clear about whether you're getting stuck in the debugger, because some settings (like readtable-case) may be changed within the debugger for the sake of convenience.  E.g.,

```
* (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert)

:invert
* (defun hi () "hello")

hi
* (HI)
; in: HI
;     (|hi|)
; 
; caught style-warning:
;   undefined function: HI
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     HI
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002FDE7D3}>:
  The function COMMON-LISP-USER::|hi| is undefined.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

("undefined function")
0] TOP
```

We entered **TOP** to get out of the debugger.  You can enter **?** to get a list of available commands.  Now that we're back to the top level REPL, we can see that **(HI)** will have the same result.  This time, we'll try executing **(HI)** from within the debugger, too:

```
* (HI)

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002FDE7D3}>:
  The function COMMON-LISP-USER::|hi| is undefined.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SYMBOL-FUNCTION |hi|)
0] (HI)                   ;; within the debugger

"hello"                   ;; "HI" must have been read as "HI", not "hi"
0] TOP
```

From within the debuger, **(HI)** worked just fine.  It must be resetting back to some "standard" values to make life easier for programmers.  After entering **TOP**, though, we're back to the REPL, and **(HI)** will fail again:

```
* (HI)

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002FDE7D3}>:
  The function COMMON-LISP-USER::|hi| is undefined.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SYMBOL-FUNCTION |hi|)
0]
```

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't seem to respect the setting.

Comment: @William The code you've shown so far doesn't illustrate where that seems to be the case, I think.  Can you include an actual transcript from the REPL that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Run `(HI)` a second time and you'll see  what I mean. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YYhw7Nze

Comment: @William Running `(HI)` a second time, I get the same kind of error.  But that's *after* leaving the debugger.  I think you might be running `(HI)` the second time while you're still *in* the debugger?

Comment: That is probably it, how do I leave the debugger?

Comment: @William On my system, you can type TOP.  But in any case, you can type ? to see a list of commands

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90559/discussion-between-william-and-joshua-taylor).

Comment: @William I've added some more explanation and examples to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your example does not work:

```
* (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert)

:invert
* (defun hi () "Hi!")

hi
* (HI)
; in: HI
;     (|hi|)
;
; caught style-warning:
;   undefined function: HI
;
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     HI
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION:
  The function COMMON-LISP-USER::|hi| is undefined.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

("undefined function")
0]
```

Note that `0]` means we are in the debugger at level 0, which has the normal readtable case. Get out of the debugger, just look at the instructions printed, by typing `0` and we are back at the top-level listener - where the readtable case is still `:invert`.

If you read the what SBCL prints: `(invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name)`. Then you see `0` is `[ABORT]`. So you invoke it by number. Just type `0` and return. You can also type `abort`.

Typing `HELP` to the debugger explains it...

If you compile a file with the contents

```
(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert)
(defun hi () "Hi!")
(HI)
```

, then the first form will have no effect to the compile time environment, since the compiler does not execute that piece of code. It just compiles it. The reader is not changed. It would be changed when loading the code. See `EVAL-WHEN` to have top-level code executed at compile time.

Comment: Run `(HI)` a second time and you'll see  what I mean. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YYhw7Nze

Comment: @William: Get out of the debugger, which uses its own readtable case and try again. No problem.

Comment: Plus one, although Joshua answered 1st and got to the root probably first so I'm going to give it to him.