# get symbol-name without uppercase

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is it possible in Common Lisp to get a `symbol-name` without the uppercase result?

```lisp
(symbol-name 'aAbB)
;; => "AABB"

(OTHER_FUNCTION? 'aAbB)
;; => "aAbB"
```

I would like to use a symbol name as a string but case-sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your symbol is *actually* all uppercase, because the *reader* already upcases it.  In order to prevent that, you can either use a different readtable-case or escape the symbol, using either enclosing pipe symbols: `'|aAbB|` or a backslash for the next character: `'\aA\bB`.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a full answer on this question: [Why is Common Lisp case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375537/why-is-common-lisp-case-insensitive)

"The *readtable* objects has an attribute, readtable-case, that controls how the reader interns and evaluates the symbols read. you can setf readtable-case to :upcase(default), :downcase, :preserve, :invert.

By default, the readtable-case is set to :upcase, which causes all symbols to be converted to upcase."